# Open workbook and copying info code doesnt copy values as expected

Tags: excel, vba, copy

So I made the following code to copy-paste info from another workbook to the current one but it is not recognizing the information and only the drop-down list info in the destination file.

```
Sub casesopenfile()
    Dim filetoopen As String
    Dim Casesbook As Workbook    
    
    filetoopen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Choose a file", Filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *xls*,(.*xlsx*),*xlsx")
    
    If filetoopen = "False" Then
        MsgBox "No file selected", vbExclamation, "Sorry"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set Casesbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(filetoopen)
        Casesbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:Q300").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cases 2017-2021").Range("A1121").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Casesbook.Close False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: "*doesnt copy values as expected*" is not a useful error description. Please explain what you expect and what wents wrong or where you get errors. Also screenshots might help to understand your issue. Imagine we have no idea what your code should do unless you explain it to us. I see actually nothing wrong with that code. It copies range `A1:Q300` of the opened workbook and pastes into `A1121` of `Cases 2017-2021`.

Comment: ... except the possible *... large amount of data...* message (before closing the workbook) which can be suppressed with `Application.CutCopyMode = False`.

Comment: Might be an issue with a hidden sheet in the first position?  Make sure there are no hidden sheets in the workbook you're copying from, or if there are, that they're not positioned before the sheet you want to copy from.

Comment: Also make sure the first sheet is a worksheet and no other sheet type (like a chart sheet). `Sheets` contains **all** type of sheets while `Worksheets` only contains worksheets.

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel a bit dumb but there was a hidden sheet and now works perfectly. I appreciate you all :)